Spring Authorization Server How many endpoints are there
I want to know how many endpoints are built in spring authorization server. Is there any document for reference? Including the URL and function of other endpoints
I can't find the relevant introduction in github. Can I send the link to the document
At present, I know/oathu2/token endpoint

You can see the endpoints and their functionalities under "Protocol Endpoints" section of the Spring Authorization Server docs. If you want to see the default endpoints, you need to browse through the filters that implement these endpoints and read the code.
Eg: For the authorization endpoint, you may refer to OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter and in the code, you'll see DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT_URI = "/oauth2/authorize".
